# Form in not sending the button data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a strange behaviour in my form, it sends the data from the textboxes but it doesn't send the button data.

This is my form:

```
<form name="login_registro" method="POST" id="login_registro">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password">

    <input type="submit" name="hacer_login" style="width:auto; height:auto; padding:5px;" class="button" onclick="submitForm('{{matches|last}}/entrar')" value="entrar">

    <input type="submit" name="registro" style="width:auto; height:auto; padding:5px;" class="button" onclick="submitForm('{{matches|last}}/registro')"  value="regístrate gratis!" >
</form>
```

The submit function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action) {
    document.getElementById('login_registro').action = action;
    document.getElementById('login_registro').submit();
}
</script>
```

In the two pages (entrar and registro) I did a print_R($_POST); and it only shows the two inputs, username and password. It doesn't shows the button pressed.

If I remove the onclick function, and add an action="page.php" it sends the two inputs plus the button pressed.

I know I can do a workaround, but I would like to know why this happend. Thanks.

PS: I commented all jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function submitForm(action) {
    document.getElementById('login_registro').action = action;
}
```

I didn't understand at all your answer @Vicentiu Bacioiu, but you gave me a cue. How you said the form is submitted twice, so removing the line where it submit the form in the function worked for me.

Comment: Basically if you have <input type='submit'> when you press that it's going to submit the form. if you add an additional handler to that (a function that does form.submit) that is another submit.

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that using `onclick` and submitting the form, will submit twice because the submit button already sends the form, and you add `form.submit()`

Use `onsubmit="return submitForm('actionName')"`. If you return `true` at the end of the function, the form will get submitted. If you return `false`, the submission will be cancelled.

You can do this more elegantly by not setting the action dynamically and sending it as a field of the form, or parameter (set through the `submitForm` function), but this implies changes to your server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will upvote you, but can't mark you as answered, I added the answer myself. **Thanks!!**